# How to test that a certain URL resolves to a specific state

Tags: angular-ui-router

I'm using UI Router with my Angular setup, and I'd really like to test / ensure that a specific URL resolves to a specific state (even better if I can inspect the resolved `$stateParams` values as well).

It's pretty trivial how to do this the other way around; that is, resolving from a state with parameters and inspecting the URL that gets resolved:

```
var resolvedUrl = $state.href('some-state', { foo : 123 });
resolvedUrl.should.be('/somestate/123');
```

But how would I flip that around? The `$state` service doesn't seem to have methods on doing that, and I can't seem to identify any service in the UI Router API that I can hook onto for this.

Comment: Have you read any of UI-Router's official tests?

Comment: @ChrisT ~ of course. Are you saying that the tests do this somehow? Must have missed it if yes.

Comment: @ChrisT ~ oh man. [Just found it](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/test/stateSpec.js#L791). This blows. Thanks.